# Pagination with Firebase v9 and React not working

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to build a page that paginates all the data from a collection, however I can't seem to figure out how to do it and I haven't found anyone who's done it either.
I've tried to get the `documentList.length`, but that also isn't working.

```
function Sessions() {
  const location= useLocation();

  const user= location.state.user;

  const [sesList, setSesList] = useState([]);
  const subRef=collection(db, 'Users',user,'Sessions');

  let q = query(subRef,orderBy('time','desc'),limit(5));

  const DocumentSnapshot=getDocs(q);
  const last= DocumentSnapshot[DocumentSnapshot.length-1]

  const next=()=>{
    return q=query(subRef,orderBy('time','desc'), startAfter(last), limit(5))
  }

  const prev=(first)=>{
    return q=query(subRef, orderBy('time','desc'), endBefore(first['time','desc']), limitToLast(5))
  }
  
  


  useEffect(() => {  //loads all the tenants
    
    onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
     setSesList(
        snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }))
      );
      
      
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    

    <div className='Sessions'>
      <Sidebar className='nav'
        L1={<Link to='/Dashboard' state={{user:user}}>Dashboard</Link>}
        L2={<Link to='/Sessions' state={{user:user}}>Sessions</Link>}/>

        <div className="bod">
          <div className="startCard1">
            <h1>Sessions</h1>

          </div>

          <div className="Recent">
          <h1>Your Sessions:</h1>
          <div className="recSes">
          {sesList.map((REC)=>{
              return(
                <div className="rowCard">
                  <div className="rowCardTitle">
                   <h3> Subject: {REC.subject}</h3>

                  </div>
                  <div className="WTime">
                    <h3>Work Minutes: {REC.WorkTime}</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div className="BTime">
                   <h3> Break Minutes: {REC.BreakTime}</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div className="Atime">
                    <h3>Date: {REC.time}</h3>
                  </div>
                  
                </div>
              )
            })}
          </div>
          </div>
          <div className="buttoninlin">
          <button  className='Gobtn1'>Previous </button>
          <button className='Gobtn1' onClick={next}>Next</button>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Sessions
```

expected result: next button shows next documents, back button shows previous documents

Comment: None of your code seems to call the `prev` function that you defined.

Comment: I’ve tried implementing it but it doesn’t do anything

Comment: For context, I'm using the last and first variables in prev and next to get the last document and first doucment respectively but I can't seem to get it to work

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). And please, do not use smileys in your posts. Stack Overflow strives to be a professional knowledge database for programming problems, not your friendly neighbourhood help desk.

Comment: @Adriaan There's nothing wrong with being a friendly neighborhood help desk. :)
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356329/is-it-acceptable-to-use-a-casual-and-jokey-style-in-posts/356333#356333